# response-splitting tag name is misspelt

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

As per https://security.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/66101

> This tag appears to be misspelled.  One would expect 'response-splitting' with a double 't'.  If this could be corrected without breaking any existing connections it would likely be advantageous.

Comment: Done! thanks :-)

Comment: I thought this tag was about defending against multiple spiteful acts. Silly me.